# How to keep trying to establish connection in Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

If the server is not up when I try to run the following code, I just get a Connection refused error.

How can I make the sender below to keep trying to establish connection and perhaps sending until the remote server is indeed up and the connection is successfully established?

```
HOST = client_ip    # The remote host
    PORT = port        
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(msg)

    if expect_receive:
        received_data = s.recv(1024)
        print received_data
        #client has started

    s.close()
    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about brute force? Something like this

```
import time
while 1:
    HOST = client_ip    # The remote host
    PORT = port       
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    except:
        print("FAILED. Sleep briefly & try again")
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
    s.sendall(msg)

    if expect_receive:
        received_data = s.recv(1024)
        print received_data
        #client has started

    s.close()
    return
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am using ssl with threads and the following works for me.

```py
import socket, ssl
from threading import *
from _thread import *
from time import sleep

HOST_1, PORT_1, CERT_1 = '127.0.0.1', 443, 'certificate_1.pem'
HOST_2, PORT_2 = '127.0.0.1', 4430

def enviar():
    #global morte;
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH);
    context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
    context.check_hostname = False;
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile='certificate_2.pem');
    conn = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=HOST_2);
    
    while True:
        try:
            conn.connect((HOST_2, PORT_2));
            break;

        except:
            print("\n=====Failed connection=====\n");
            sleep(1);#vital, without it the script raises an exception 

    try:
        while True:
            x = input("--> ");
            x = bytes(x, "utf-8");
            conn.write(x)
            print(conn.recv().decode())

    except ssl.SSLError as e:
        print(e);
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e);

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n====Bye!====\n");            

    if conn:
        conn.close();
        #morte = True;

###################
#parte original abaixo
def receber():
  sock = socket.socket(); 
  sock.bind((HOST_1, PORT_1)); 
  sock.listen(5);  
  context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH);
  context.load_cert_chain(certfile=CERT_1, keyfile="private_1.pem")  # 1. key, 2. cert, 3. intermediates
  context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1  # optional
  context.set_ciphers('EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH')

  while True:
    conn = None;
    ssock, addr = sock.accept();
    try:
      conn = context.wrap_socket(ssock, server_side=True);
      while True:
        print(conn.recv());
        conn.write(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n%s' % conn.getpeername()[0].encode());
        
      break
    except ssl.SSLError as e:
      print(e)

    except Exception as e:
      print(e);
      if conn:
        conn.close();
        
    finally:
      if conn:
        conn.close()

  print("End!");
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
  start_new_thread(receber, ());#1
  start_new_thread(enviar, ());#2
```

If you run in association with another similar script (using other private key and certificates, obviously) it will run mostly ok, but, it will raise an:

```
EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2472)
```

I am still trying to figure out how to deal with it.